# AjaxForm не отправляет письма MODX

Tags: php, modx

При отправке письма через AjaxForm с FormIt не приходят письма, хотя сообщение удачной отправки есть, + в базу письмо сохранятся. Думал не работает функция mail(), но при тестовой отправке

`<?php
mail('viktorkrav4uk87@gmail.com', 'Subject', 'Body');`

все работает.

Сам снипет вызиваю так

```
[[!AjaxForm?
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`main_form_ru`
    &hooks=`spam,email,FormItSaveForm`
    &emailSubject=`Тест`
    &emailTo=`viktorkrav4uk87@gmail.com`
    &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
    &emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl`
    &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
]]
```

Comment: Вроде нашел сам причину нужно добавить &emailFrom=`любое_слово@домен.ru`
пока все заработало

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для корректной работы сниппета нужно добавить `&emailFrom=<текст>@домен.ru`

В итоге прийти к виду:

```
[[!AjaxForm?
    &emailFrom=`<текст>@домен.ru`
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`main_form_ru`
    &hooks=`spam,email,FormItSaveForm`
    &emailSubject=`Тест`
    &emailTo=`viktorkrav4uk87@gmail.com`
    &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
    &emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl`
    &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
]]
```